Is there an irrational number $\alpha$ such that the max value of $(\{m\alpha\})_{m\geq 1}$ is never an integer multiple of that sequence's min value?
Tangential to this question.
Given an irrational number $\alpha > 0$ define $c_m = \{ m\alpha\}$ where $\{ x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$.
Now, define two sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ as follows:
$$ a_n = \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} c_m, $$
$$ b_n = \min_{1\leq m \leq n} c_m. $$
Does there exist an irrational $\alpha$ such that $a_n$ is never an integer multiple of $b_n,$ except when $n=1?$
Obviously, this requires $\{\alpha\}>1/2.$ What else?

If $c_p=kc_q$ for some integer $k$ we have $p\alpha=kq\alpha+r$ for $p,q,r,k$ integers or $\alpha=\frac r{p-kq}$ which cannot be the case if $\alpha$ is irrational unless $p=kq$ and $r=0$.  The last is what you avoid with $\{\alpha\} \gt \frac 12$
